# pg_catalog.pg_class.relfilenode after truncate

Tags: postgresql

I have a view depends on a table: create view hello_v as select * from hello;
To retrieve the referenced table name from a view name, I think pg_class and pg_depend tables may be useful.
Truncating on the table results in no entry in pg_depend.

How to come back pg_depend.refobjid which is equals to pg_catalog.relfilenode ?

I can reproduce my point of view:

```
select version();

create table hello(name text);
create view hello_v as select * from hello;

select c.relname, c.relfilenode from pg_catalog.pg_class c inner join pg_catalog.pg_depend d on d.refobjid = c.relfilenode
    where c.relname in ('hello', 'hello_v') group by relname, relfilenode order by c.relname;

 relname | relfilenode
---------+-------------
 hello   |      305818
 hello_v |      305824

truncate hello;

select c.relname, c.relfilenode from pg_catalog.pg_class c inner join pg_catalog.pg_depend d on d.refobjid = c.relfilenode
    where c.relname in ('hello', 'hello_v') group by relname, relfilenode order by c.relname;

 relname | relfilenode
---------+-------------
 hello_v |      305824

 -- I hope to exist a record where relname = hello and relfilenode = xxx
```

Or simply:

```
create table hello(name text);

select c.relname, c.relfilenode from pg_catalog.pg_class c inner join pg_catalog.pg_depend d on d.refobjid = c.relfilenode
    where c.relname = 'hello' group by relname, relfilenode order by c.relname;

truncate hello;

select c.relname, c.relfilenode from pg_catalog.pg_class c inner join pg_catalog.pg_depend d on d.refobjid = c.relfilenode
    where c.relname = 'hello' group by relname, relfilenode order by c.relname;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your join condition is wrong.  You want to join against c.oid, not relfilenode.

This shows your table correctly:

```
select c.relname, c.relfilenode from pg_catalog.pg_class c inner join pg_catalog.pg_depend d on d.refobjid = c.oid
where c.relname = 'hello' group by relname, relfilenode order by c.relname;
```